# Can't pass a variable with Jinja in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

The form's action sends the input to a route named soldfor. I am trying to pass the variable ID into soldfor. When I hit the submit button I get this error:

> TypeError: soldfor() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

**Rendering of register_results.html:**

```
return render_template('register_results.html', results=results, ID=ID)
```

**register_results.html:**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('soldfor', ID={{ ID }}) }}">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Sold For" autocomplete="off" name="soldfor">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" name="soldfor" value="soldfor" type="submit">Sell!</button>
        </span>
      </div>
  </form>
```

**soldfor Route:**

```
@app.route("/soldfor", methods=["POST"])
def soldfor(ID):

    soldfor = request.form['soldfor']

    print(soldfor)

    g.db = connect_db()

    g.db.execute("UPDATE yardsale SET SF = ? WHERE ID = ?", (soldfor, ID,))

    g.db.commit()
    g.db.close()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: You should check out the quickstart if you haven't already. It will explain the basics of routing and passing URL parameters. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this:

`<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('soldfor', ID={{ ID }}) }}">`

to this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('soldfor', ID=ID) }}">
```

Also from the documentation:

> When you define a route in Flask, you can specify parts of it that
>   will be converted into Python variables and passed to the view
>   function.

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username):
    pass
```

> Whatever is in the part of the URL labeled  will get passed
>   to the view as the username argument. You can also specify a converter
>   to filter the variable before it’s passed to the view.

```
@app.route('/user/id/<int:user_id>')
def profile(user_id):
    pass
```

Your error is being caused by the route expecting a parameter, but you are not passing one in. You should probably use something like that last example to accomplish what you're trying to do.

It's also sometimes desirable to pass a default value into the view function in case you need to use that URL without passing an ID. An example would look like this:

```
@app.route('/user/id/<int:user_id>')
def profile(user_id=0):
    pass
```